# my Cursor always displaying true

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have constructed some piece of code to search whether the string value is already present within a sqlite table. Here is what i have:

```
public boolean findvalue(String item) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor checkIfExist = db.rawQuery("SELECT *    FROM "+ Table_item + " WHERE " + "itemName= " + "'" + item+ "'", null);
    checkIfExist.moveToFirst();
    if (checkIfExist.moveToFirst()){

        return true;}
    else{
        return false;}

}
```

code inside main:

```
Store.setOnClickListener(
         new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override public void onClick(View v) {

              boolean s= myDatabase.findvalue(item.getText().toString());

                 if (s= true) {
                     Toast.makeText(createAcc.this, "item has been created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }else if (exists = false) {
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " " + Title.getText().toString() + " Exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
             }
           }

 );
```

It always gives me true even though the item string value is present inside the table. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: use cursor.getCount() instead of cursor.moveToFirst()

Comment: 1- `if (s= true)` is not correct, should be `if (s==true)`
2- `It always gives me true even though the item string value is present inside the table` your current code supposed to do this, it will return true if the value was found, your condition to check `s` should be with `!`, i.e `if (s != true)`

Answer (score 0):

1- `if (s = true)` is not correct, should be `if (s==true)`

2- It always gives me true even though the item string value is present inside the table your current code supposed to do this, it will return true if the value was found, your condition to check s should be with !, i.e `if (s != true)`

3- for this particular case, `getCount()` may suite better.

```
public boolean findvalue(String item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor checkIfExist = db.rawQuery("SELECT *    FROM "+ Table_item + " WHERE " + "itemName= " + "'" + item+ "'", null);
    return checkIfExist.getCount()>0;
}
```

**Extra:**

better make use of parameters option in `rawQuery()`

```
Cursor checkIfExist = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ Table_item + " WHERE  itemName= ?", new String[]{item});
```

Comment: [queryNumEntries](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) would be even better.

Comment: @CL. correct. i tried not to change much code from OP